# What program/app is renaming files with "yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss" as the filename?

Tags: file-transfer

My pictures folder has a bunch of renamed pictures and movies, with many duplicates all the sudden.  All the renamed files are named with this date/time format: yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss.

Original files are named yyyymmdd_hhmmss as per Samsung's convention.  New files seem to be mostly duplicates with some originals mixed in as well, so I can't just erase them all.

What program/app is causing the rename and copy? And why are there some originals but many duplicates?

I have an android phone. Camera upload to dropbox used to be turned on, though some dupes are also from my regular camera.  I also rebuilt two computers from XP to Win7 recently, though I don't see how any file copies could have caused this behavior.  (extra files are found on one of the Win7 machines.) I used some duplicate finders, windiff style programs, and merge programs during the process.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?